# xtgmath.h: error C2059 when converting project to VS 2012 from VS 2010

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

At my work I am in the process of migrating a project from VS 2010 Express to VS 2012 Professional.  I get the following error in the xtgmath.h file when trying to compile it:

xtgmath.h(70): error C2059: syntax error : '('

I found no explanation or resolution for this from searching around the web.  I am confused because this is a standard header file.  Here is a snipet of the code from the header file it is crashing on.  It gives three of these errors for every file which uses the math.h lib.  The intellisense is giving me an error when I hover over __cdecl, __CRTDECL and __CRTDECL which reads: "Error: a calling convention may not be followed by a nested declarator"

```
extern "C" double __cdecl pow(_In_ double, _In_ double);
float __CRTDECL  pow(_In_ float, _In_ float);
long double __CRTDECL  pow(_In_ long double, _In_ long double);
```

I greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: `<math.h>` is deprecated in C++.  You should use `<cmath>` instead.

Comment: It is a new header file for VS2012.  This is typically a macro problem, generate the pre-processed file to see what the compiler sees.

Comment: `<xtgmath.h>` is deep internal details. There's nothing wrong with the code snippet that you showed; the problem is in the code that uses it, which you didn't show.

Comment: Looks like it was a macro that I overlooked.  The "pow" function was redefined in my code so correcting that fixed this issue.  Thanks everyone again for the help!

Comment: Anyone landing here- if you're migrating OLD code, if you've got fltk ancient code (circa 2010), the math library included also calls math.h from MSVC. So you've got to find those links and edit as well...